# Verificar caracteres especiais input

Tags: php

Estou tentando validar meu formulário e capturar caracteres especiais usando `preg_match(..., ...)`, porem sem sucesso. Tanto usando **@** ou sem ele, me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> Caracteres especiais detectados, se tiver usando **@**, remova-o.

O que está errado neste código?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ttrSignin'])) {
  $ttrUsername = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ttrUsername'));
  $ttrPassword = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ttrPassword'));

  if (empty($ttrUsername)) {
    $error[] = 'Insira seu nome de usuário do Twitter.';
  } elseif (empty($ttrPassword)) {
    $error[] = 'Insira sua senha do Twitter.';
  } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/", $ttrUsername)) {
    $error[] = 'Caracteres especiais detectados, se tiver usando <strong>@</strong>, remova-o.';
  } else {
    #restante do codigo
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: o que você chama de caracteres especias? aspas simples e aspas duplas podem passar pelo regex? Varios espaços em branco é aceitavel?

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo básico de *bloquear* caracteres especiais é:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $username) {
    echo 'Username OK!';
}
else {
    echo 'Username tem caracteres inválidos...';
}
```

No seu caso você pode fazer isto:

```
elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $ttrUsername)) {
  $error[] = 'Caracteres especiais detectados, se tiver usando <strong>@</strong>, remova-o.';
}
```

Prontinho. Veja se funciona!

Comment: Funcionou mas será que bloqueia todos mesmo?